# ToroPHP routing - 404 action

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, routes

I'm using the ToroPHP for routing.

- **Docs:** https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP/blob/master/README.md
- **Source:** https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP/blob/master/src/Toro.php

**My code:**

```
Toro::serve(array(
    "/" => "home",
));

Toro::serve(array(
    "/website/:string" => "website",
));

// Fired for 404 errors
ToroHook::add("404",  function() { echo '404 error'; });
```

**More code**

Toro:serve goes to this class, works fine, for both `home` and `website`.

```
class home {
    function get() {
        echo 'My home';
    }
}

class website {
    function get($slug) {
        echo $slug;
    }
}
```

**Htaccess**

This is how my htaccess file looks like. It's just a little bit rewritten to work on localhost.

**Look at the last row...**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_localhost_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Problem**

If I go to a page that I have setup with `Toro::serve`, it works just fine.

***If I go to a URL that is NOT defined, it gives me a white screen.***

I would expect it would give me "404 error" by the hook I added. What do I do wrong?

**Example:** If I go to /nocontent/ it gives me a white screen, and response 200 ok.

Comment: Are you rewriting all requests to sub directories to index.php? Otherwise, your request won't reach PHP since Apache cannot find the specified file.

Comment: @alexn I updated my code with /website/ which also works. It echos my slug 'whatever' when I go to /website/whatever/. However /nocontenthere/ gives a white screen. I don't use folders, just virtual URLs, but the classes that works are included in a folder but that should not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you redirect all requests to index.php. This is done by using mod_rewrite. Place the following in your .htaccess folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Second, you are using `Toro::serve` the wrong way. You should not make multiple calls to serve. Instead, pass multiple routes to the first call:

```
Toro::serve(array(
    "/" => "home",
    "/website/:string" => "website",
));
```

Last, *add the 404-hook before calling serve*. Otherwise, it won't be found:

```
ToroHook::add("404",  function() {
    echo "404 - Not Found";
});
```

Comment: I use a rewritten htaccess to make it work well on my localhost. However, both steps, moving the hook first AND make all calls in the same array did the trick! Works fine now!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the hook definition has to come *first*, i.e.

```
<?php

ToroHook::add("404",  function() {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    echo '404 error';
    exit;
});

Toro::serve(array(
    "/" => "home",
    "/website/:string" => "website",
));
```

Also, make sure you have a **.htaccess** file re-writing all requests to **index.php** as per the docs. I should know, being a contributor to the project ;)

Furthermore, there should only be *one* call to `Toro::serve()`; you just pass an array to it with the URL pattern as the key and the route to call as the value as per my example above.

Comment: I saw you updated it on github now, nice! Just as a sidenote, I did not get the original htaccess-file work on a localhost environment. Maybe mine is better (in my question above)?

Comment: @JensTörnell Hi Jen. Just go with what works. If you’re getting white screens of death then it’s worthwhile to keep an eye on your PHP error log so you diagnose the issue and see what fatal errors are halting script execution.